# moving the hard disk to a new PC

Tags: server, hardware

I've got an Ubuntu server 12.04 installation on a desktop.

I suspect something wrong with the motherboard.

If I move the hard drive to a new box will there be any issues with drivers or is it expected to run readily?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never had any problems moving a hard disc from 1 machine to another machine. And I do this regularly. I do tend to try to match the new system with the old system though (ie. same brand but a newer model).

If applicable there is 1 concern and that is the display driver. If you use nVidia/AMD drivers and move to AMD/nVidia I suggest removing that driver first. But on a server I doubt those are active: in general the terminal itself is connected directly to the server and does not have fancy options that warrant prop. drivers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had a minor problem with the network card not being detected. I fixed it with the solution here: http://www.serenux.com/2009/11/howto-fix-a-missing-eth0-adapter-after-moving-ubuntu-server-from-one-box-to-another/

Comment: @itsols gratz! May that new system live long and prosper.